# Error: 'Run Time: Error 9' in Macro Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

We are currently facing a new issue that only affects one user's system. We have a Macro workbook that functions correctly for everyone except this particular user, who is encountering a 'Run Time: Error 9'.

How can I debug this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest). Also please consult the helpcente, especially [ask]. Do not ever use screenshots of textual information like code.

Answer (score 2):

`Break on All Errors` in enabled on the user's pc.

- `Break on All Errors`: pause the code on all types of errors, even when you've implemented error-handling techniques (e.g. On Error Resume Next).
- `Break in Class Module`: pause the code on all unhandled errors. Additionally, it will pause within objects (e.g. userform) and pinpoint the line which raises the error.
- `Break on Unhandled Errors`: it is the default setting and ensures that any unhandled errors are brought to your attention. For Userforms, it won't highlight the line causing the error within the object; instead, it will highlight the line referring to that object.

Change VBE setting `Error Tracking` as below

[image]

Comment: Would you edit this answer to say what the consequences/purpose of following these instructions will be?